# How can solve the UniqueFieldConstraintViolationException db4o

Tags: java

The code run ok, but give me a Exception that I can't controlle, This is the console message:

```
The person with this DNI es already exists
Exception in thread "main" com.db4o.constraints.UniqueFieldValueConstraintViolationException: class: Vehiculo field: matricula
    at com.db4o.constraints.UniqueFieldValueConstraint$1.ensureSingleOccurence(UniqueFieldValueConstraint.java:66)
    at com.db4o.constraints.UniqueFieldValueConstraint$1.onEvent(UniqueFieldValueConstraint.java:97)
    at com.db4o.internal.events.Event4Impl.trigger(Event4Impl.java:78)
    at com.db4o.internal.events.EventRegistryImpl$4.run(EventRegistryImpl.java:123)
    at com.db4o.foundation.DynamicVariable.with(DynamicVariable.java:54)
    at com.db4o.internal.InCallback.run(InCallback.java:24)
    at com.db4o.internal.events.EventRegistryImpl.withExceptionHandlingInCallback(EventRegistryImpl.java:279)
    at com.db4o.internal.events.EventRegistryImpl.commitOnStarted(EventRegistryImpl.java:121)
    at com.db4o.internal.LocalTransaction.dispatchCommittingCallback(LocalTransaction.java:89)
    at com.db4o.internal.LocalTransaction.commit(LocalTransaction.java:66)
    at com.db4o.internal.LocalTransaction.commit(LocalTransaction.java:59)
    at com.db4o.internal.LocalObjectContainer.commitTransaction(LocalObjectContainer.java:689)
    at com.db4o.internal.LocalObjectContainer.close2(LocalObjectContainer.java:94)
    at com.db4o.internal.ObjectContainerBase.close1(ObjectContainerBase.java:361)
    at com.db4o.internal.ObjectContainerBase.close(ObjectContainerBase.java:344)
    at Principal.main(Principal.java:38)


import com.db4o.Db4oEmbedded;
import com.db4o.ObjectContainer;
import com.db4o.ObjectSet;
import com.db4o.config.EmbeddedConfiguration;
import com.db4o.constraints.UniqueFieldValueConstraint;
import com.db4o.constraints.UniqueFieldValueConstraintViolationException;
import com.db4o.query.Query;


public class Principal {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        EmbeddedConfiguration config = Db4oEmbedded.newConfiguration();
        config.common().objectClass(Persona.class).objectField("dni").indexed(true);
        config.common().add(new UniqueFieldValueConstraint(Persona.class, "dni"));


        ObjectContainer bbdd = Db4oEmbedded.openFile(config, "databaserrr.db4o");

        Persona p = new Persona("Pepe2", 25, "50667847L");

        try{
        bbdd.store(p);
        bbdd.commit();
        System.out.println("Se ha guardado correctamente");
        Query q = bbdd.query();
        q.constrain(Persona.class);
        ObjectSet<Persona> res = q.execute();
        }catch (UniqueFieldValueConstraintViolationException e) {
        System.out.println("The person with this DNI es already exists");
        }finally{
            bbdd.close();
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
Persona Class


public class Persona {
    //Cremos atributos
    private String dni;
    private String nombre = null;
    private int edad;


    public Persona() {
    }
    //Constructor
    public Persona(String n, int e, String d) {
        nombre = n;
        edad = e;
        dni = d;

    }

    //Getter y setters
    public String getDni() {
        return dni;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public int getEdad() {
        return edad;
    }

    public void setDni(String d) {
        dni = d;
    }

    public void setNombre(String n) {
        nombre = n;
    }

    public void setEdad(int e) {
        edad = e;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the solution to catch the exception:

```
catch (UniqueFieldValueConstraintViolationException e) {
        System.out.println("The person with this DNI es already exists");
bbdd.rollback();
}
```